SPO: Conditional Options In List Based on Another Column
Lets say I have one multiple choice column named Department and another called Field in a SharePoint List, and I want the options in Field to depend upon the choice in Department. So, if someone picks Social Sciences in Department, the options in Field will be Economics, Sociology and so on. If they pick Natural Science, the options will be Physics, Chemistry and so on.
I found this question with answers for SharePoint 2013, but the links are dead and the answers probably don't transfer directly to SharePoint Online.
Currently, I am doing this by having the options spread out over multiple columns (per the example above, one for Social Science and another column for Natural Science).
Is it possible to do this in SharePoint Online?

Unfortunately, this is not possible using SharePoint Online out of the box features to have dependent (cascading) drop downs in the SharePoint list forms.
However, you can customize the SharePoint list form using Power Apps and create dependent (cascading) drop downs in the SharePoint list forms using Power Apps formulas.
Refer below Microsoft official documentations and tutorials to achieve dependent (cascading) drop downs functionality:

Customize a Microsoft Lists or SharePoint form by using Power Apps
Create dependent drop-down lists in a canvas app
Working with Cascading Lists in SharePoint and Power Apps


Maybe you could try a custom content type or use metadata to implement a cascading drop-down list.
Please refer this article: 3 alternatives to building cascading drop-downs in SharePoint
